# Transferring a File in android

Tags: java, android, stream, media

I have been struggling for two days to try and understand the process of copying a file to the SD card in Android. None of the methods I tried thus far seem to work.

My application has a Profile Picture setting. I need to launch an Intent to pick an Image, then I need to copy the Image to a new Path on the SD Card and then return the Uri of the new Image at which point I check the Images Orientation (Samsung Pics seem to be rotated 90 degrees sometimes). I then rotate the Image correctly and then save the Uri to a SharedPreferences File for use in the Application.

This is my Intent Call:

```
case R.id.ib_userImage:

    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    break;
```

This is my current horrific attempt at the copy function, I have changed it so much I am not very lost.

public static void copyImage(Context context, Uri uri) {

```
    Log.i("ATTENTION", "Inside the Copy Function");
    Log.i("ATTENTION", "Trying to copy file: " + uri.toString());

    try {

        String outputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/appname/images/";

        File dir = new File(outputPath);

        if(!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        Log.i("ATTENTION", "Destination File Created at: " + dir.toURI().toString());

        InputStream in =  context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dir);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while(in.read(buffer) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer);
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("ATTENTION", "File Copied");
}
```

Thank you for the help, I will provide any other information you might need.

Update:

I am now getting the Following Exception During the Write Process

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/appname/images: open failed: EISDIR (Is a Directory);

My Understaing is that I specified a Directory with the following code:

```
 String outputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/medinfo/images/";

    File dir = new File(outputPath);

    if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
```

and then passed it to the OutputStream:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dir);
```

and the OutputStream would create the file for me within that Directory.

I didn't think that was actually trying to open the Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual problem. Don't ignore the count returned by `read().`

```
while ((count = in,read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

**EDIT** Your directory problem is cured by:

```
dir.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

and removing the redundant existence check. At present you are creating the file itself as a directory.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem and cleared up a few things for me. You really helped me a bunch :).